# How to add an update to existing SQL Loader control file?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-loader, controlfile

How to create an external table from my text file and use that to update to real table, rather than creating a (normal) staging table and using SQL*Loader.

sample.ctl

```
load data 
infile 'data.txt'
append into table newtable
fields terminated by '|' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(ACCOUNTNBR)
```

data.txt

some raw datas..

```
54545554
54542145
65656566
58787788
```

Comment: Don't repeat the question, [improve the existing one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). Have you looked at the [documentation I linked to before](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm#SUTIL011)? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. The file, info.dat, created with data identified above.
2. Set-up a default directory (which contains the data source) and to grant access to it (need the CREATE ANY DIRECTORY privilege):

   CREATE DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir AS '/usr/apps/datafiles';

   GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY ext_tab_dir TO SCHEMA_OWNER;
3. Create an external table named newtable_load:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE newtable_load
   (ACCOUNTNBR NUMBER
   )
      ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
      (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY default_directory
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       FIELDS (ACCOUNTNBR NUMBER)
      )
      LOCATION ('info.dat')
   );
   ```
4. Load data from the external table newtable_load into the table newtable:

INSERT INTO newtable (ACCOUNTNBR)
(SELECT ACCOUNTNBR
FROM newtable_load);